# Erlang and Java interfacing

Tags: java, functional-programming, erlang

I am particularly interested in knowing the performance implications of the Erlang component when doing this kind of interfacing.

After learning about Erlang I thought that it might be useful to code certain components of an application in Erlang where I need to use the high concurrency and throughput that it provides. Has any one tried/seen this kind of scenario before? What has been the experience so far?

Comment: what sort of bandwidth are you looking for?  If we are talking about a low throughput, what is the issue?

Comment: ... and further more, if you have lots of data to pass around, why not dump it in a file and just "ship" the file path on the Jinterface?

Comment: I am looking forward to implementing a component in Erlang which requires high throughput (else I would have gone the Java route). Also because the message/data passing that this proposed Erlang component would do, would actually be of small size.

Interfacing Java and Erlang would certainly lead to a degradation in the performance (in terms of throughput) of the Erlang component and I wanted to know if anyone has had any experience with that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single general answer for this, there is only relevant benchmarks for you to implement.